# cannot read SQLite database file in an Eclipse Plugin project

Tags: database, eclipse, sqlite, eclipse-plugin

I am REALLY new to Eclipse plugin developement, so maybe my question sounds dumb, but I've been googling for hours...

Whats the way to load an SQLite db into my Eclipse plugin?

First I created a standalone Java application, it loaded, and processed the database file just file, but when I added the code (well copied the files to the new project) it says:

```
java.sql.SQLException: no such table: measurement
```

The db file is in the projects root dir.

I thought this issue is caused becouse the applicaiton cannot find the database file, so I changed the filename from test.db to asdftest.db, and I got the same error, so the problem was this indeed.

Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
public List<Coord> generateModel() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            Connection conn = DriverManager
                    .getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
            Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stat
                    .executeQuery("select * from measurement where has_gps = 'TRUE';");

            LinkedList<Coord> nodes = new LinkedList<Coord>();

            while (rs.next()) {
                nodes.add(new Coord(rs.getString("_id"), rs.getString("lat"),
                        rs.getString("lon")));
            }
            rs.close();

            conn.close();

            return nodes;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```